# Como utilizar uma conta do hotmail/outlook para enviar e-mail em c#

Tags: c#, envio-de-email

Estou tentando utilizar uma conta para enviar e-mail, com meu projeto em c#, utilizando o `namespace System.Net.Mail`, porém eu não consigo autenticar no servidor do outlook, ele me lança a exceção:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Caixa de correio não disponível. A
>   resposta do servidor foi: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not
>   authenticated'

Segue meu código:

```
private void Email()
{

     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
     client.Port = 587;
     client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
         new System.Net.NetworkCredential("meuemail@outlook.com", "minhasenha");
     client.EnableSsl = true;
     client.Credentials = credentials;
     client.TargetName = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
     try
     {
         MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
         mail.From = new MailAddress("ricardopulini@outlook.com",string.Empty,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
         mail.To.Add (new MailAddress("destinatario@mail.com"));
         mail.Subject = "Teste de e-mail";

         mail.Body = "Teste de e-mail";
         client.Send(mail);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         throw ex;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Verifique nas configurações de segurança da sua conta MS. Você provavelmente deverá permitir alguma opção de uso.

Answer (score 1):

**Este código me atende bem:**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("remetente", "destinatario");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "senha");

client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

mail.Subject = "teste";
mail.Body = "teste2";

client.Send(mail);
```

Além de ir nas configurações do Hotmail e habilitar o uso de aplicativos, nas configurações de conta.

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado eu não estou conseguindo encontrar onde habilita isso na conta?

Comment: Meu código está igual o seu, mas não acesso, acredito que seja isso mesmo, no google eu consegui, mas na conta da microsoft eu não encontro.

Comment: Exitem duas questões: 1-habilitar opções de pop em configurações->conta    2- verificar em https://account.microsoft.com/account se há algum dispositivo que não esteja liberado.

Comment: Outra coisa: tentou colocar hotmail.com no lugar de outlook.com no seu email

Comment: O POP esta liberado e sim eu tentei com hotmail também!

Comment: testou com outro e-mail?